# Join or add column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables **users** and **comments**.

In term of performance, should i use a join (with user id) to get the username from **users** table or should i add a column username to the **comments**, so i won't need join for only 1 data (username) but i will need to add one more data for each comment (username).

Is join slow if there's a lot of comments in the table ?

Wich one should i do ? Join or add column username to comments.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Join is probably the best so you're not storing data in two places.  What if a user name is changed? It won't change the user name for the comments.  Also, joining two tables is not very time consuming.

Comment: just be sure you use proper indexes

Comment: Changing the username is not important for the website. If there's a good difference in performance i can easily live without it.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you're going to see considerable performance differences either way. Maybe a little more one way or another, but I'm thinking milliseconds.

Comment: Ok i will use join. Just to be sure correct index is user_id = primary key in users table and user_id = index in comments table ? Username needs index ?

Comment: The user table should have the user_id as a primary key. The comments table should have a commentid as a primary (unique) key. You can use indexes on the user_id to improve performance, yes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number of users and comments. Having a [denormalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) db, which is what you ask, can be faster but then you need to take care yourself to update username in both tables. Don't forget to add index for userid in comments table if you go the join way.
So the correct answer I believe is go with the join, and denormalize later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using InnoDB, you can add the column and add foreign key restrictions. This will allow you to increase efficiency and worry less about updating indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The one reason why you would store the user name in the comments table is if you wanted to know the user name when the comment was created.  If the user name is subsequently changed, you'll still have the name at the time of the comment.

In general, though, you want to use join.  You want to have the primary key on a table defined, probably as an auto-incremented (identity) integer value.

If you are concerned about performance for getting all comments for a single user, then you should build an index on the comments table on the user id field.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would rather user two simple separate queries. I do not like joins all that much. Joins just produce duplicated data by definition. You might want to check http://www.notorm.com/ that is a simple php db access layer going joinless way.

Comment: I would vote this down, but I bountied my reputation to low. Two separate queries requires more requests between a server and a database. Generally, MySQL can handle itself faster than trying to process things programatically.

Comment: I just pointed out what works best for me. There are no redundant data transferred so it is easier to work with such result data in the application itself. I've never experienced any performance issues yet.